# Adding microseconds to Timestamp and assigning to Host variable in DB2 - BIND ERROR FROM BUILD

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe, zos

I've been struggling with this for far too long and can't seem to wrap my head around what really is the issue.

As an input I receive from caller TMS = 2020-01-02-03.04.05.060708. I then want to achieve the following - but my build ends in BINDLOG ERROR  (see bottom).

```
DCL TMS        CHAR(26);
DCL START      CHAR(26);
DCL END        CHAR(26);

      IF                    TMS ^= ''                    
        THEN 
           DO;         
             EXEC SQL SET :START = TMS + 1 MICROSECOND;     
             EXEC SQL SET :END   = TMS + 30 DAYS;
          END;
        ELSE
           DO;         
             EXEC SQL SET :START = '0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000';
             EXEC SQL SET :END   = CURRENT TIMESTAMP;
          END;
```

Seems like TMS is not properly set to the respective Host varriable, even though TMS is in fact a timestamp. Looking at the documentation only seems to confuse me more. Any clues as how to perform arithmetic actions on date/time variables?

I have tried adding days to a date format which worked fine. But adding days, or microseconds to a TIMESTAMP is causing me lots of headache. The below works like a charm, just struggling to understand why?

```
DCL TMS_VALID CHAR(10);
DCL TMS_EMPTY CHAR(10);
    
  IF                    TMS ^= ''                    
    THEN 
       DO;
         TMS_VALID           = SUBSTR(TMS,1,10);  
         EXEC SQL SET :START = DATE(:TMS_VALID);  /* Would like to add 1 microsecond to :START*/
         EXEC SQL SET :END   = DATE(:TMS_VALID) +  30 DAYS;
      END; 
    ELSE  
       DO;
         TMS_EMPTY           = SUBSTR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,1,10);
         EXEC SQL SET :START = DATE(:TMS_EMPTY) - 30 DAYS;
         EXEC SQL SET :END   = DATE(:TMS_EMPTY);
      END;
```

Below is the BINDLOG. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
DSNX200I  :DB2A BIND SQL ERROR       
           USING TSTSD AUTHORITY     
           PLAN=(NOT APPLICABLE)     
           DBRM=AB12345              
           STATEMENT=455             
           SQLCODE=-206              
           SQLSTATE=42703            
           TOKENS=AB12345I.TMS  
           CSECT NAME=DSNXORSO       
           RDS CODE=-225             
DSNX200I  :DB2A BIND SQL ERROR       
           USING TSTSD AUTHORITY     
           PLAN=(NOT APPLICABLE)     
           DBRM=AB12345              
           STATEMENT=456             
           SQLCODE=-206              
           SQLSTATE=42703            
           TOKENS=AB12345I.TMS  
           CSECT NAME=DSNXORSO       
           RDS CODE=-225
```

Comment: `EXEC SQL SET :END   = TMS + 30 DAYS;` Why should `TMS` be interpreted as a host-variable? There is no colon `:`. Waht about ` EXEC SQL SET :END   = :TMS + 30 DAYS;`

Comment: Hi Piet. Thank you for your comment.

```EXEC SQL SET :END   = TMS + 30 DAYS;```  <-- Wont work and will result in the Error Bindlog as I posted in the bottom.

```TMS_VALID           = SUBSTR(TMS,1,10);  
         EXEC SQL SET :START = DATE(:TMS_VALID); 
         EXEC SQL SET :END     = DATE(:TMS_VALID) +  30 DAYS;```  <-- Will work, but this only applies to when i cast TMS to DATE format.

Comment: Your pasted code is still missing the colon before `TMS`!